# npm broken after update

Tags: node.js, npm

I just updated npm using `npm install -g npm@latest`, because I installed a package that required a newer version.
Now when I run any npm command, even `npm --version`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: npm v10.2.4 is known not to run on Node.js v14.15.4.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
C:\Users\suitendaal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\agents.js:105
    options.lookup ??= this.#options.lookup
                   ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\suitendaal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\index.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

I already found items on stackoverflow about using nvm to install versions of NodeJS, but apparently I am not using this (I installed it years ago and don't remember how). My OS is Windows.
How do I fix this error and install the correct versions of npm and NodeJS?

Comment: Please see the error: "ERROR: npm v10.2.4 is known not to run on Node.js v14.15.4.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the installer from [npm downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current) then install, it might fix the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of version incompatibility, update your node to 18 or higher, or downgrade you npm version

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same error. fixed it by installing the latest version of node using `nvm package manager`.

To install or update nvm, you should run the install script. To do that, you may either download and run the script manually, or use the following `cURL` or `Wget` command:

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
```

```bash
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
```

After installing nvm you should just install npm to update it to the latest version

```bash
nvm install node
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I usually install my node version using `fnm`. Turns out that I had indeed installed an older version of node via the nodejs Installer, and that became the default version of the system.

But when I did some brew update previously, my system npm got updated to the latest version, hence the mismatch.

The fix for me is to remove `node` and `node_modules` in `/usr/loca/bin` folder.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node; rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Or another alternative is to install the latest LTS version via the Installer from https://nodejs.org/en

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and solved it by setting the default version in NVM.
First, check what is the currently configured version of Node.js

```
nvm list.
```

To change it, use

```
nvm alias default <version>
```

Restart the terminal to see that it has worked by running again

```
nvm list again.
```